# Divide variable if the rest is same

Tags: sas, enterprise

I have an example table as below

```
     id     term   subj    prof        hour
     20    2016    COM    James         4
     20    2016    COM    Henrey        4
     30    2016    HUM    Nelly         3
     30    2016    HUM    John          3
     30    2016    HUM    Jimmy         3
     45    2016    CGS     Tim          3
```

I need to divide hours if the id- term and subj same. There are 2 different prof with same id:20 - term and subj, so i divided hour 2.
There are 3 different prof with same id : 30 - term and subj. So i divided hour 3. 
So the output should be like this;

```
id   term     subj   prof         hour
20    2016    COM    James         2
20    2016    COM    Henrey        2
30    2016    HUM    Nelly         1
30    2016    HUM    John          1
30    2016    HUM    Jimmy         1
45    2016    CGS     Tim          3
```

Answer (score 0):

In SAS you can use a double DOW loop to achieve this, once the data has been sorted in the correct order.  The first loop counts how many profs there are with the same id, term and subj.  The second loop divides hour by the number of profs.  The loops are performed at each change of id, term or subj.

I've created a new_hour variable and kept in the temporary _counter variable just so you can see the code working, you can obviously overwrite the hour variable and drop the _counter variable if you wish

```
/* create initial dataset */
data have;
input id term subj $ prof $ hour;
datalines;
20    2016    COM    James         4
20    2016    COM    Henrey        4
30    2016    HUM    Nelly         3
30    2016    HUM    John          3
30    2016    HUM    Jimmy         3
45    2016    CGS     Tim          3
;
run;

/* sort data */
proc sort data=have;
by id term subj prof;
run;

/* create output dataset */
data want;
do until(last.subj); /* 1st loop*/
set have;
by id term subj prof;
if first.subj then _counter=0; /* reset counter when id, term or subj change */
_counter+first.prof; /* count number of times prof changes */
end;
do until(last.subj); /* 2nd loop */
set have;
by id term subj;
new_hour=hour / _counter; /* divide hour by number of profs from 1st loop */
output; /* output record */
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is as simple as the one you gave as an example, one proc sql should suffice. If it is more complicated, please explain how so we can be more helpful!

```
data have;
    input id term subj $ prof $ hour;
    datalines;
    20    2016    COM    James         4
    20    2016    COM    Henrey        4
    30    2016    HUM    Nelly         3
    30    2016    HUM    John          3
    30    2016    HUM    Jimmy         3
    45    2016    CGS     Tim          3
    ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as select
        *, hour / count(prof) as hour_adj
        from have
        group by id, subj;
quit;
```

Comment: I don't think you want the `DISTINCT` keyword in this case. It would delete duplicate rows that might exist in the original data.